# Are there any AFOL clubs in the Atlanta area?

Tags: afol

Are there any AFOL clubs in the Atlanta area? If so, do they have current contact information? I did some Googling but the results were inconclusive and I thought I'd shoot this out to the community.

Sorry if it's too specific or localized, but that's good I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be anything aside from the [North Georgia LEGO Train Club](http://www.ngltc.org/), but it looks like you could start one from the [Waiting List - AFOL](http://afol.meetup.com/members/us/ga/atlanta/) there also appears to have been a newsgroup [lugnet.loc.us.ga.atl](http://news.lugnet.com/loc/us/ga/atl/).

Comment: That's a great idea. I just started one - http://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Adult-Fans-of-LEGO